# How me set restriction input?

Tags: reactjs

If the length of the input text is less than 6 characters, then display a warning on the page that the length is less than 6.

```
showText2(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ text2: value });
    if (this.state.symbols.length < 6) {
      console.log('Текст меньше 6');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use formik and yup for that if dont want to hard code it

Answer (score 0):

You can use onChange method as well like

```
onTextChange(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 let value = e.target.value;

 if (value < 6) {
   console.log('Text must be greater then 6 char');

   //you can take two more state like error and errormessage

   this.setState({ text2 : value , error : true , errormessage : 'value must be greater then 6 char' })

 }else{

  this.setState({ text2 : value , error : false , errormessage : '' })

 }

}
```

Then you can show your message using your state value of error and errormessage